# jquery.find doesnt return data in ie 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

```
<H1 class=extraBottomMargin>Tell us the name of your employers</H1>
        <UIWIDGET>
            <FIELDSET>
                <DIV>
                    <INPUT id=viewEnterEmployerNames_q1 tabIndex=1 maxLength=75 placeholder="Employer">
                </DIV>
            </FIELDSET>
        </UIWIDGET>
        <DIV class="rightRail watermark"><IMG src="app/img/RR_Watermark.png"></div>
```

I run a command `jQuery("above html").find("UIWIDGET").html()`

This works in all browsers except IE 8. Please advice.

Note that uiwidget is my custom tag, so please ignore the part of suggesting any improvements on that.

Answer (score 2):

There is no HTML tag named `UIWIDGET` - and in older IE versions accessing non-standard tags won't work without creating them first.

You can easily do so by calling `document.createElement('UIWIDGET')` - that's what libraries such as html5shiv do for the HTML5 elements.

In case you plan to use some HTML5 tags anyway you could add [html5shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/blob/master/dist/html5shiv.js) and run the following code before including the html5shiv script: `html5.options.elements += ' uiwidget';`

However, it would be **much better** if you did not use invalid HTML tags at all!

Comment: Probably they fixed this annoying behaviour in IE9

Comment: It's pointless that you point out that your code works in IE9 you might as well say 'it works in chrome!', your question wasn't about IE9.

The html5shiv is for IE8 and lower, as ThiefMaster they fixed HTML5 tags in IE9. Also you would be better off without a custom tag, I can't think of something at the top of my head you would be able to do with a custom tag that you couldn't using classes and custom attributes.

Comment: thank you folks...i got a hack for this for IE.. <mytag xmlns='mytag'>
  Just Some Text
</mytag>.....we just need to insert xmlns='uiwidget' for this to work

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns:custom="http://www.test.com">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body>
<H1 class=extraBottomMargin>Tell us the name of your employers</H1>
        <custom:uiwidget>
            <FIELDSET>
                <DIV>
                    <INPUT id=viewEnterEmployerNames_q1 tabIndex=1 maxLength=75 placeholder="Employer">
                </DIV>
            </FIELDSET>
        </custom:uiwidget>
        <DIV class="rightRail watermark"><IMG src="app/img/RR_Watermark.png"></div>
</body>

<script>    
$(function() {
   alert($("uiwidget").html());
});
</script>
```

This will work in IE but `WON'T` work in other browsers!!!
That's the official way for IE to define and support custom tags.
This reflects on `.getElementsByTagName()` method, so I see no way to search custom tags like `<mytag>` in IE doesn't matter if you use jQuery or other library or just directly invoking `.getElementsByTagName()`. Searching Google you can find many official and unofficial articles about this issue.

Comment: thank you folks...i got a hack for this for IE.. <mytag xmlns='mytag'> Just Some Text </mytag>.....we just need to insert xmlns='uiwidget' for this to work